# How to fix Execution Expired Error in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

I have a Rails website on Heroku with the Unicorn server. I occasionally am notified of errors  like the following one:

> ActionView::Template::Error: execution expired
>   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)

This is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree
//= require jquery.qtip.js
```

The error logs don't show clearly what caused such an error. For example, a recent log is shown below. What could be causing such errors, or how should I diagnose them?

Unicorn config:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
worker_processes Integer(ENV["WEB_CONCURRENCY"] || 3)
timeout 15
preload_app true
#...
```

Catch timeout:

```
#timeout.rb
Rack::Timeout.timeout = 13
```

Logs:

```
app/web.2:  Started GET "/articles/20" for ...
heroku/web.1:  Cycling 
heroku/web.1:  Stopping all processes with SIGTERM 
app/web.1:  Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT 
app/web.1:  Unicorn worker intercepting TERM and doing nothing. Wait for master to send QUIT 
app/web.1:  Unicorn master intercepting TERM and sending myself QUIT instead 
heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path=/articles/20 host=... dyno=web.2 connect=1ms service=79ms status=200 bytes=8123 
app/web.1:  I,  INFO -- : reaped # worker=0 
app/web.1:  I,  INFO -- : reaped # worker=2 
app/web.1:  I,  INFO -- : reaped # worker=1 
app/web.1:  I,  INFO -- : master complete 
heroku/web.1:  Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM 
heroku/web.1:  Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL 
heroku/web.1:  Process exited with status 137 
heroku/web.1:  State changed from up to down 
heroku/web.1:  State changed from down to starting 
heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 14131 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is actually caused by rendering application.js, you probably managed to turn off asset precompilation, because otherwise that file would be precompiled and just be a file to serve which can hardly ever time out.

Check of asset precompilation and re-enable it, if it is actually disabled.

If that is not the case the file probably is pretty huge, the you should reconsider if you actually use everything in your javascripts asset folder.

Comment: I get the following message when pushing to Heroku "Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation", but shouldn't that only affect the first visit to the site?

Comment: Not necessarily. Every so often Heroku winds down your instance and fires up a new one, and then the cached file goes away. That is if it does even cache it in a file and not only in memory which would make it even more volatile.

Comment: Either way fixing asset precompilation will likely fix your problem.